# How to have inner select inside pdo queries?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm not sure how to name the question exactly, and since I wasn't able to have a better title I wasn't able to search much for the same issue that might have been asked before.

I have a one to many relationship in my database, the data is spread across a few tables.

```
public function get_recipe_data($id){
    $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM
                               recipe as recipe
                               LEFT JOIN recipe_introduction as introduction
                               ON recipe.id = introduction.recipe_id
                               LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients as ingredients
                               ON recipe.id = ingredients.recipe_id
                               LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients_notes as notes
                               ON recipe.id = notes.recipe_id
                               LEFT JOIN recipe_macros as macros
                               ON recipe.id = macros.recipe_id
                               WHERE recipe.id = :id
    ');
    $sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();

    return $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function convertCategoryId($category_id){
    $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT name FROM recipe_categories WHERE id = :category_id');
    $sth->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();

    return $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

In the recipe table there's a column that has an id for category name, and refers to another table.

**recipe table**

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id | title | category_id |
+--------------------------+
| 1  |  ...  |      1      |
+----+-------+-------------+
| 2  |  ...  |      3      |
+----+-------+-------------+
```

I have this other table

**recipe_categories**

```
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
| 1  |  breakfast |
+----+------------+
| 2  |    lunch   |
+----+------------+
| 3  |   dinner   |
+----+------------+
| .. |    ...     |
+----+------------+
```

Right now I'm having to return the results from the first query above, and then once I have that, I run another method in the class passing the category_id from the first query, and then match it to the recipe_categories, but that's so inefficient.

Is there a way for me to be able to select the name straight off from the first query?

Comment: This has nothing in particular to do with PDO, it is a pure SQL question. You obviously know what JOINs are already, so explain what's stopped you from JOINing the category table as well, to get the name from it via the id ...?

Comment: @CBroe I'm doing the "walk of shame" right now, completely embarrassed..  need to hit the sack. You're right though, I should just have joined the table in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the category table to the recipe table, this will give you access to the categroty name in a single query.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM recipe AS recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_categories AS rcat ON recipe.category_id = rcat.id
LEFT JOIN recipe_introduction AS introduction ON recipe.id = introduction.recipe_id
LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients AS ingredients ON recipe.id = ingredients.recipe_id
LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients_notes AS notes ON recipe.id = notes.recipe_id
LEFT JOIN recipe_macros AS macros ON recipe.id = macros.recipe_id
WHERE recipe.id = id
```

Note. Whilst it appears common practice amongst PHP users to use "select *" the best practice is you should specify each and every column that you want returned and not leave it to chance.